# Oriented object javascript : initialize an attribute with a self function call

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, attributes, initialization

I have this class made in javascript :

```
function MyClass(id) 
{
    this.attribID = this.getID(id);

    // ==========================================================================
    this.getID = function(id) { return ("tooltip_" + id);   }
    // ==========================================================================
}
```

When I call it from my HTML with :

```
<script>
var a = new MyClass("onecell");
</script>
```

it generates this error : `this.getID is not a function`

How may I init my attribute with a generic function defined inside MyClass, function that can also be called from many other places than the init one ?

Comment: Try declaring `getID` before calling it.

Comment: Put `this.attribID = this.getID(id);` after function definition.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos—if a function declaration is used, it can be anywhere in scope, it doesn't have to be "before" being called. However, since the OP has used a [*function expression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), then it must be before the call since the assignment doesn't occur until the statement performing the assignment has been executed.

Comment: @RobG yes, you're right, I should've explained better.

Comment: @RobG : Thank you for this precision. Can you develop a bit, I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "if a function declaration is used, it can be anywhere in scope" and I'm not reaaly used with Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clarifying what was sugested by @RobG

There are two ways of doing it.

Change the order of assignments:

```
function MyClass(id) 
{
    this.getID = function(id) { return ("tooltip_" + id);   }
    this.attribID = this.getID(id);
}
```

Or using the class prototype:

```
function MyClass(id) 
{
    this.attribID = this.getID(id);
}

MyClass.prototype.getID = function(id) { return ("tooltip_" + id); };
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the this.getID function like so: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gummiah/c6LnD/)

```
function MyClass(id) 
{
   // ==========================================================================
   this.getID = function(id) { return ("tooltip_" + id);   }
   // ==========================================================================

   this.attribID = this.getID(id);
}
```

Comment: Or put the *getID* method on *MyClass.prototype* and make sure the assignment occurs before an attempt is made to create an instance.